# How to use css selectors like jQuery in XPath (PHP)

Tags: php, xpath, css-selectors

Firstly, I am having as a reference for XPath this nice guide: https://devhints.io/xpath

However, I am unable to find what I am looking for into a DOM.
For example, let say that we have the below DOM:

```
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <div class="preheader"></div>
        <div class="description"></div>
        <div class="productbox">    
            <div class="content"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content"></div>
</body>
```

I would like to find

```
#main .productbox .content
```

How I must write it, using the guide I have shared above?

Comment: if you are looking for equivalent xpath `//div[@class='producybox']/div[@class='content']`

Comment: @supputuri What about the `#main` id attribute?

Comment: check my answer.

Comment: @Alejandro xpath that been used here is identifying the element uniquely, so `//*[@id='main']` is optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the xpath.

```
//div[@id='main']//div[@class='producybox']/div[@class='content']
```

General notation for the xpath.

**xpath with single attribute** `//tag[@attribute='attribute_value']`

**xpath with multiple attributes:** `//tag[@attribute1='attribute1_value' and @attribute2='attribute2_value']`